# Multiple mimetypes for File Transfer Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, mime-types

I want to transfer an image with any extension. Currently I have my code as:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = 'file';
options.fileName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
```

Even if I upload a `.gif` or a .`png` file, its sent over as `.jpeg`. What do I need to put in `options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";` ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it to

```
mimeType: "multipart/form-data"
```

It will allow for selecting different types of image.